# Logisim Problem

Tags: transistors, pcb, digital-logic, logic-gates, logisim

I designed two or latch, one with or gate, and another one with transistors, but the one I designed with transistors wont work as expected.

Can anyone please tell me if it has a logical problem or if logisim causes that problem ?

here is the image :

[image: http://imgur.com/a/B4p36]

My or gate doesn't work as expected

I used logisim app to create these circuits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not tech support for software. Ask electrical design questions please

Comment: Note that logisim doesn't accurately simulate transistors. @laptop2  this is electrical design

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a simulator issue. The circuit is invalid.

The big problem with pass transistor logic is that it's outputs are not compatible with its own inputs. You can't connect the bottom common node directly to the gate of one of the transistors and expect it to do anything useful.

At a minimum, you'd have to add a gain/level-shifting stage to that path, and that complicates things to the point where it's better to use a different circuit topology altogether.

Comment: could you design the correct circuit that act like the right circuit (in the above picture) ?

Answer (score 0):

If those transistors are Nchannel, with +VDD at top, then those are source-followers, with gain of 0.9 or so.
Your Nch has gain < 1. put two inverters in series between the output and that gate.